# OLS - Predeterminedness and moment condition

Tags: regression, time-series, least-squares, generalized-moments

I'm having trouble validating if following procedure to test for predeterminedness is plausible. Given the linear model:

$y_t=\beta_1+\beta_2x_{1t}+\beta_3x_{2t}+\epsilon_t$

Having $x_{2t} = y_{t+1|t}+v_t$ and $\epsilon_t$ uncorrelated with $x_{1t}, x_{2t}$. 
And $\epsilon_t$ i.i.d. with $E(\epsilon_t)=0, E(\epsilon_t^2)=0$. Given $v_t$ i.i.d. and also uncorrelated with $\epsilon_t$.

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
E[x_{1t}\epsilon_t] & = E[E[x_{1t}\epsilon_t|x_{1t}]] \\
 & = E[x_{1t}\underbrace{E[\epsilon_t|x_{1t}]]}_{=0} = 0 \\
E[x_{2t}\epsilon_t] & = E[E[x_{2t}\epsilon_t|x_{2t}]] \\
 & = E[x_{1t}\underbrace{E[\epsilon_t|x_{2t}]]}_{=0} = 0 \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Can anyone confirm this?